# How to get sub items from an array in Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Given this JSON:

```
case studies: [
  [ "Nubaru",
    ["Nubaru Yearly Report", "Web design", "2013", "/case-studies/Nubaru.html", "/images/case-studies/Nubaru.png"]
  ],
  [ "Ekande",
    ["Ekande application", "Web application design", "2013", "/case-studies/Ekande.html", "/images/case-studies/Ekande.png"]
  ]
]
```

And this Liquid (using Jekyll):

```
<ul>
{% for items in page.case-studies %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <li>
      {{ item }}
      <!-- How to get sub items? -->
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

- How would I access the data in the inner array?
- Is there a way to name the data so I might access it like this: {{ case-study.date }}?

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, have you tried using a third loop like `{% for subItem in {{ item[2] }} %}`, or accessing directly, like for the data `{{ item[2][3] }}` ?

For the second one, you can use `{% assign %}` like this: `{% assign caseDate = 'your-value' %}`, cf. http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid#Variable_Assignment