# Loop through the first 3 items of an array in Liquid

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a site that lets you browse through gifts that people want based on information surveyed from people (I will just survey a small amount of people unless the site has some attention - I am not worried about creating a very large list on the site, but that is not what I am here to ask about).

I'm coding the site with Jekyll, so of course I need to use Liquid.

You see, I would like to sort through the first 3 items in the [`site.posts`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/) array.

I looked over the [array filters documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/array-filters), but I can't seem to find anything that does what I need to get done.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466362/how-to-get-sub-items-from-an-array-in-liquid), but I'm not entirely sure how to understand the answer on there, because I don't know what a "third loop" is, and the way I'm looping through posts wouldn't work well with accessing the array data by using `site.posts[0]`, `site.posts[1]`, and so on. It would make the code bulky, but I guess I can do that if I need to.

This is the code I have right now:

```
<h2>Recently added gifts</h2>
<div class="posts">
    {% assign posts = site.posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    {% unless post.list  %}
    <div class="post">
        <h3 class="post-title">
            <a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h3>

        <time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</time>

        <p class="post-excerpt">
          {% if post.description %}
            {{ post.description | strip_html }}
          {% else %}
            {{ post.excerpt | strip_html }}
          {% endif %}
        </p>
    </div>
    {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure of what you are trying to achieve here.
To loop through the 3 first occurrences in an array you may use something like {% for post in posts limit:3 %} but my guess is that you are looking for something more sphisticated. Would you mind to clarify your question?

Comment: I tried limit:3 and it seems to work. I didn't know that existed. Sorry for asking such a basic question..

Comment: No problem :). I'll add the comment as answer as it might help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in comment and as the answer might help somebody else, you may set a limit as a parameter when you loop through an array, like this:

```
{% for post in posts limit:3 %}
    Do something
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: now how to start loop from index 4

Comment: {% for post in posts limit:3 offset:5 %}
        Do something
    {% endfor %}

Put 5 as param if your index (and it should) starts at 0.

Infos here:https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags#for-offset